# C# call a Tel: or Call: URI

Tags: c#, call, tel

I have an application on my PC that responds to Tel: and Call URI calls.

How do I make such a call from a C# application.

All the searching I have done has failed to provide an answer.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You state you have an app that responds to calls and then ask how to make such a call. Do you want to make or receive a call?

Comment: I want to make a call via the app that responds to Call: and Tel:

Comment: You are still unclear. It seems you want to make a call. That involves using Telephony; for which there are plenty of 3rd party libraries. Search for TAPI. Not sure what you mean by responds to call: and Tel:? please elaborate.

Comment: Like this but calling from C#

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709071(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: So in other words call the following from a C# program


<a href="callto:0605040302" >0605040302</a>.

Comment: Once again you veer into the weeds. You have put an html address reference and say "call the following". Where does the html come from? You can parse the html and remove the phone and feed that to your TAPI client, asking it to dial. Your link points at NetMeeting.CallToURL syntax. Are you using Netmeeting? or you just want a callto system like that?

Comment: @JonFarmer you said you have the application that responds to TEL or CALL Uri, can you help me on that I spent alot time on it, I have the windows application and I need that whenever user hits anchor with TEL opens my application in which I get the phone number

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string url = "http://www.google.com";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
```

The above example would start the end users default browser and navigate to google's home page, since the browser is registered to handle the "http" uri-schema, in your case however:

```
string url = "callto:12345";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url); // should start your app.
```

the app which is registered (in the client's environment) to handle the "callto" ("tel:","call:", etc.) uri schema, should then take over.